# Image not visible in a webmap from QGIS2WEB

Tags: qgis, web-mapping, qgis2web, community

I have got a map created in QGIS where there are some pictures linked to a different polylines. Those pictures are stored in an image hosting, therefore I got a field in the polyline´s attribute table with the url to those images. Afterwards, I have created a webmap with QGIS2WEB. So far, all ok, I guess.

My issue is that in the popup window in the webmap does not show the images. How could I fix this?

As I said, I got my pictures stored in a image hosting and I would like keep them there.

[image: This is all I got]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the images are externally hosted, you need to create a text field (*not* using a QGIS image edit widget), and populate that field with HTML `<img>` tags.

So, if your image location is `https://www.hello.com/pics/234.jpg`, your field value should be:

`<img src="https://www.hello.com/pics/234.jpg" />`

If you can also add `alt` text, this will improve the accessibility of your map.

Comment: Thank you Tom. I was struggling with this and that has worked perfectly. Much appreciated.